# What does "indexvalue" mean and what is it used for?

Tags: html

I'm wondering what indexvalue means and what it is used for. It's used here

```html
<img indexvalue="17" width="160px" src="/Special/CapImg/aityckg4d3NVYTB4cU5xOUFIdjVKSHoxRlVOaTgwY3doVWErc0h6NXVqL3hSQUFBb3JvWFc0azBtc2hFNG9vK3JKM3dvcGZGc1FxMUJUQUVpN3JTU3c9PQ==.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is as `data-info` for get information.

[Here is indexvalue](https://kissanime.ru/Special/AreYouHuman2?reUrl=%2FAnime%2FNaruto-Dub%2FEpisode-211-Memory-Of-Flames%3Fid%3D104078%26s%3Ddefault)

There each image have own number. It use for data-info, for check captcha.

This validator throw error as this attribute not valid HTML.
https://validator.w3.org

> Error: Attribute indexvalue not allowed on element img at this point.

Comment: I got this piece of code from https://kissanime.ru/Special/AreYouHuman2?reUrl=%2fAnime%2fNaruto-Dub%2fEpisode-211-Memory-Of-Flames%3fid%3d104078%26s%3ddefault. That might help.

Comment: Yes, but is that how your suppost to implement a custom attribute?

Comment: @JoeHill I use `data-myname="my-any-data"`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a valid HTML attribute. That being said, it is still accessible using JavaScript and is probably being used to determine which image the user clicked on.

Comment: Yes, but would the invalid HTML attribute mess up the whole page?

Comment: @JoeHill No, it will not affect the page at all. The browser will simply ignore it.